# Does the definite integral of this function exist?

Tags: calculus

I encountered this integral the other day $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{-1}{(t-1)^2}dt$ and tried to evaluate it. I finally arrive at $\frac{x}{x-1}$ as my final answer. My question is, is this a legal thing to do, since there is an asymtote at x=1 and the area under curve seems to be infinite?

Comment: It's not legal if $x\geq 1$; the integral is improper and diverges at $1$.